# Print binary data WScript

Tags: vbscript, wmi, wsh

I am using the last example on this page in WMI to print out some Windows System Log information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394593(VS.85).aspx

I would also like to print out the binary data as well, but I am not sure how to do that in WScript.  Here is my modified code:

```
' test.vbs
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colLoggedEvents = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent " _
        & "Where Logfile = 'System' and SourceName = 'MySource'")
For Each objEvent in colLoggedEvents
    Wscript.Echo "Category: " & objEvent.Category & VBNewLine _
    & "Event Code: " & objEvent.EventCode & VBNewLine _
    & "Message: " & objEvent.Message & VBNewLine _
    & "Time Written: " & objEvent.TimeWritten & VBNewLine _
    & "Event Type: " & objEvent.Type & VBNewLine _
    & "Binary Data: " & objEvent.Data
Next
```

I get this error message from Windows Script Host when running test.vbs:

> Error: Type mismatch, Code: 800A000D, Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error

Any idea how to print the data out as a hex character string?

Answer (score 1):

`.Data` is an array of integer values (little endian encoded wide characters from the looks of it). You'd need to `ChrW()` each pair of numbers and concatenate them to a string before you could print the data. A function like this might work:

```
Function ToStr(arr)
  ToStr = ""
  For i = 0 To UBound(arr) Step 2
    ToStr = ToStr & ChrW(arr(i) + arr(i+1)*256)
  Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. This led me down the right path. I ended up with this code:<br>
`function BinaryToString(arrValue)  <br>
 strInfo=""  <br>
  for i=0 to ubound(arrValue)  <br>
   strInfo=strInfo & right(hex(arrValue(i)+256),2) <br>
  next  <br>
 BinaryToString=strInfo  <br>
end function`